# Automated Testing of a Webview

Tags: reactjs, webview, automated-tests, functional-testing

Talk to me QAs!

Has anyone done automated tests (E2E) of a webview mobile app (developed in react) ? The application does not open on the web, only on mobile devices.

If yes, which testing framework did you use?

Obs.: I don't want to use appium or robot.